# JSON array manipulation Angular 5 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a case like i want to add key, value pair to an object in angular 5 typescript. that should look like below

Expected output:

```
{key1 : val1, key2 : val2, key3 : val3}
```

Actual output:

```
[{kek1 : val1}, {key2 :  val2}, {key3 : val3}]
```

Actual code tried:
//forgot abot the syntax error if any

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
this.rowData.push({
      key+i : val+1
    });
}
```

When i add the set of values in string and tried to add it to array, it comes like below

```
let pairs : string = '';
 pairs = pairs.concat('key1',':','val1','',',');
this.rowData.push({
      {"pairs":"key1:val1,key2:val2"}
    });
```

in the above code i am getting extra word "pairs" and double quotes to values.

Comment: You can consider using `array#reduce`. Or use an object initially and populate key and value, instead of using an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of this has nothing todo with either array manipulation (since you expect an object) nor Angular 5 or typescript. This is plain Vanilla JS.

```
var rowData = {};
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    rowData[key+i] = val+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
rowData = {};

for(const i < 0; i < 3; i++) {
  rowData['key' + (i + 1)] = 'val' + (i + 1);
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the keys have different name pattern

Comment: @ToshkataTonev this can't fail since you're creating keys.

Comment: Sorry, i had different expectations result in my head.

Comment: @ToshkataTonev no problem, just making it clear for other people